# Procedure or function 'IssueBook' expects parameter '@quantity', which was not supplied

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.IssueBook
(
    @bookid nvarchar(50),
    @mid int,
    @librarian varchar(10),
    @quantity int
)
AS

declare @cnt int
declare @msg varchar(100)
if not exists (select * from Books where bookid = @bookid) begin
    raiserror('Book is not available',16,1);      
    return;
end;

select @cnt = count(bookid) from issues where mid = @mid;
if (@cnt >= 2) begin
    raiserror('Maximum Limit Has Been Reached For Member!',16,1);
    return;
end;

begin tran
begin try 
    update Books set quantity = @quantity - 1 where bookid= @bookid;
    insert into issues values (@bookid, @mid, getdate(), @librarian);
end try
begin catch
    rollback tran
    /* select  @msg = error_message() */
    raiserror( 'Unknown Error', 16,1);
end catch
```

Comment: The error is pretty clear.  This stored procedure is expecting a parameter called `@quantity`.  The code which is calling this stored procedure isn't supplying that parameter.

Comment: Do yourself a favor and read the error description. It's there for a reason!

Comment: i tried but its but its giving same error pls help me its my final year project i have to submit tomorrow please

Comment: @ZoharPeled  guys pls help me out

Comment: Edit your question to include the code that is executing the stored procedure.

Comment: @GrantWinney yes i can show you the code can you give me your email

Answer (score 0):

When you call the stored procedure, be sure that you are passing a value in for all four parameters, `@bookid nvarchar(50)`, `@mid int`, `@librarian varchar(10)`, and `@quantity int`.

In this case, it looks like you're not passing in the `@quantity` parameter.

Comment: Unless we have a optional parameter. i.e. a parameter whose default value is set.

Comment: I don't see a default value assigned in the OP's stored procedure definition.